# How to show the number of direct and indirect reports for each manager?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data frame with employee id, manager id and manager email and available the emails of a few specific managers that I want to evaluate.

So far i managed to count the aggregate number of direct and indirect reports, however I cannot find a way to group by the initial line manager and get the total direct and indirect reports for each of them.

Sample data:

| employee id | manager employee id | line manager email | email address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 234567 | 3456 | marco.dull@email.com | ann@email.com |
| 699999 | 234567 | ann@email.com | smith@email.com |
| 33333 | 3456 | marco.dull@email.com | julian@email.com |
| 666666 | 234567 | ann@email.com | john@email.com** |

Output:

| manager | direct reports | indirect reports |
| --- | --- | --- |
| marco.dull@email.com | 2 | 2 |

This is my code until now:

```
select 0 as match_found,*
into #data
from clean.allemployees a
where a.reportingdate='31 oct 2020'



update d set d.match_found=1
from #data d
where d.EmailAddress in ('email1@goog.com', 'email2@goog.com', 'email3@goog.com')


update d set d.match_found=1
from #data d
where d.LineManager_EmployeeID in (
    select d.EmployeeID
    from #data d
    where d.match_found=1
)


select *
from #data d
where d.LineManager_EmployeeID in (
    select d.EmployeeID
    from #data d
    where d.match_found=1
)


select count(distinct JobTitle)
from #data d
where d.LineManager_EmployeeID in (
    select d.EmployeeID
    from #data d
    where d.match_found=1
)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: is that enough? thank you

Answer (score 0):

if only you have 1 level of indirect manager , you simply can use  join and group by like so:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #employees;
CREATE TABLE #employees
    (
        employeeid          INT
        , manageremployeeid INT
        , linemanageremail  VARCHAR(100)
        , emailaddress      VARCHAR(100)
    );

INSERT into #employees values
(234567     ,3456   ,'marco.dull@email.com','ann@email.com'     )
,(699999    ,234567 ,'ann@email.com','smith@email.com'          )
,(33333     ,3456   ,'marco.dull@email.com','julian@email.com'  )
,(666666    ,234567 ,'ann@email.com','john@email.com'           )
```

---

```
SELECT e.linemanageremail 
    , COUNT(DISTINCT e.employeeid) [direct manger] 
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN mgr.employeeid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS [indirect manger]
FROM #employees AS e
LEFT JOIN #employees mgr
    ON e.emailaddress = mgr.linemanageremail
GROUP BY e.linemanageremail
```

but if you you count indirect managers in deeper levels and count inderect manager level 1 , level 2 , etc, you need to use recursive cte and pivot, however you needto know how manely level

```
; WITH cte AS (
SELECT * ,0 level 
FROM #employees AS e
UNION ALL 

SELECT e.* , level + 1 AS level FROM cte
JOIN #employees AS e
 ON cte.manageremployeeid = e.employeeid
)

SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT cte.linemanageremail ,cte.level , COUNT(*) AS mgrc
FROM cte
GROUP BY cte.linemanageremail ,cte.level
) AS source 
PIVOT (
sum(mgrc)
FOR level IN ([0], [1])
 )AS pt;
```

if you have deeper indirect managers but you still want to count them under 'indiredt manager' group , you can change the query above to this:

```
; WITH cte AS (
SELECT * ,'direct  ' level 
FROM #employees AS e
UNION ALL 

SELECT e.* , 'indirect' level 
FROM cte
JOIN #employees AS e
 ON cte.manageremployeeid = e.employeeid
)

SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT cte.linemanageremail ,cte.level , COUNT(*) AS mgrc
FROM cte
GROUP BY cte.linemanageremail ,cte.level
) AS source 
PIVOT (
sum(mgrc)
FOR level IN ([direct], [indirect])
 )AS pt;
```